# Executing a SQL Query multiple times with different parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-scripts

I have a SQL stored procedure that I need to execute several times with different parameters.  Is it possible to execute a SQL-script of some kind that will execute multiple times with like an array or other data-structure of different parameters?  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Where do the parameters come from? A DB table?

Comment: yep.  A particular column in a table no less.

Comment: It is possible to loop through the values of a column in a table and use them as parameters in a stored procedure call. But, that could be slow. Sometimes it is better (if it's even possible) to rewrite the stored procedure as non-procedural SQL. Of course, you haven't shown your code, so it is impossible to say what's best in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a cursor (but if it's possible to restructure your code, try [YS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573542/497364)):

**EDIT**: added FAST_FORWARD as per @YS's suggestion

```
DECLARE @param INT

-- getting your parameter from the table
DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT afield FROM atable WHERE ...

OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param

-- executing your stored procedure once for every value of your parameter     
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC usp_stored_Procedure @param
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: Consider using `FAST_FORWARD` for added performance if cursor is read only & you're only moving forward. ie: `DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR...`

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably restructure the design a bit to fit the need (to workaround the cursor) - ie:

- insert values to be executed in stored proc into a temp table, then call the stored proc (the stored proc will then read the temp table)
- call stored proc using table-valued parameter